# Does Firefox v42+ support CSS Grid?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-grid

I'm doing some programming with CSS Grid and was tasked with making sure it's compatible with Firefox v42+ and IE 11+. According to caniuse.com it isn't supported by IE 11 fully nor v42 of Firefox. I have no clue how correct this information is and just wanna double check and make sure it is correct. I also can't find the documentation to check this info. Anything helps!

Edit: The duplicate answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the browsers you mention fully support Grid. IE uses an old syntax, while Firefox 42 requires a flag to be turned on. The Caniuse data matches what's on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid#Browser_compatibility.

If you need to support these browsers, you should probably use a different layout method.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help!